# Does narrowing the types of catch blocks have performance effects?

Tags: java

What are the performance connotations of changing

```
try {
  canThrowDifferentExceptions();
} catch (Exception e) {
  // handle exception
}
```

to

```
try {
  canThrowDifferentExceptions();
} catch (Exception1 | Exception2 | Exception3 e) {
  // handle exception
}
```

I see overly broad catch blocks as creating a risk of concealing exceptions that weren't planned for, but I'm curious about the performance characteristics of multi-catch.

Comment: Performance problems? It's an exception, an unexpected condition (mostly). Can you explain to me in what scenario this could ever be a bottle neck in any program?

Comment: This is definitely implementation specific.

Comment: I'm not interested in optimizing a _specific_ program, I'm attempting to investigate whether narrowing caught exception types makes sense as a _universal_ best practice.  I'm also comfortable getting implementation-specific responses.

Comment: multi-catch was a new feature on jdk 7 simply to make more easy read code and if you make the same for each catch exception.

Comment: I think the question of whether or not it's a "universal" best practice isn't really related to performance, but safety. In any case, seems like the disassembler would more or less answer this, although after JIT, pretty much most bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the exception table that in case of the multi-catch points to only one line while it points to the proper catch line on the other case.

The only other difference is the `goto` at the end of the non multi catch.

In case of a single `catch(Exception e)`, the table exception contains only one line asking for a widening conversion introducing no overhead.

Overall, based on the cost on one `goto`, **you should not expect any performance difference**.

---

Test code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        if (i == 1) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } else if (i == 2) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
             | IllegalStateException e) {
    }
}
```

versus the non multi catch the difference is:

```
32c32,36
<       37: return        
---
>       37: goto          45
>       40: astore_2      
>       41: goto          45
>       44: astore_2      
>       45: return        
//     Exception table:
//        from    to  target type
//           2    36    36   Class java/lang/NullPointerException
36,37c40,41
<            2    36    36   Class java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
<            2    36    36   Class java/lang/IllegalStateException
---
>            2    36    40   Class java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>            2    36    44   Class java/lang/IllegalStateException
```

versus `catch(Exception e)`:

```
//     Exception table:
//        from    to  target type
<            2    36    36   Class java/lang/NullPointerException
<            2    36    36   Class java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
<            2    36    36   Class java/lang/IllegalStateException
---
>            2    36    36   Class java/lang/Exception
```

Comment: This looks like the difference for the separate catch blocks to a single multi-catch block, but I'm also interested in if there used to be only a single `catch(Exception e)` block.

Comment: Edited to add the comparison